# Is it possible to give preference to one website in dedicated server?

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, website, cpanel

We have multiple websites in different cpanel accounts on our dedicated server. Can we give preference to one site or one cpanel account over others when it comes to handling requests by Apache and other resources?  Os is CentOS.

Comment: Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic at Server Fault because they customize their systems such that normal administration tools and methods no longer apply, and thus require support from the vendor or the web hosting industry. See Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?

Comment: Ok..was not sure if this is exactly a control panel question, hence asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the **iolimits** configurations per user.
In cpanel it is called **LVE manager**.